# Joomla - How to pass and retrieve parameter from URL in Article

Tags: joomla, query-string

I have list with many items. when user select the items will direct the user to the article page that have multiple image and text. The name of the image to view and the text to display are depending on the value passed.

I have implement this function before with HTML page and java using query string.
The value from query string used to give the image the 'src' attribute value using the 'id' attribute to find that image. I would like to implement the same function with joomla.
I used the following code in java before
In URL
    /class.html?id=2gb

```
</script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
           window.onload = func
           function func() {
               var className = getParameterByName('id');
               document.getElementById("classimage").src = "../images/banner/" + className + ".jpg";
               document.getElementById("className").innerHTML = className;
               document.getElementById("className").href = "class.html?id=" + className
                        }
           function getParameterByName(name) {
               name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
               var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
                   results = regex.exec(location.search);
               return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
           }
    </script>
```

In HTML

```
<img id="classimage" >
<a id="className" href=""></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can first create a [override](https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core) of your article template

`TEMPLATE_NAME/html/EXTENSION_NAME/VIEW_NAME/FILE_NAME.php`

in your case it would be :

`TEMPLATE_NAME/html/com_content/article/default.php`

once you have done this, then its time to use [jinput](https://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput)

include this Jfactory method at the top of your overriden template default.php file (`TEMPLATE_NAME/html/com_content/article/default.php`) :

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$variable = $jinput->get('varname', 'default_value', 'filter');
```

in your case it should be : `$variable = $jinput->get('id', 'default_value', 'STRING');`

now you can use `$variable` anywhere you want to show.

PS: javascipt cane be cached and not suggestible.

I hope this helps, happy coding.